# Where is configured_css generated?

Tags: css, magento2.4

I have a directory in /pub called /configed_css. It's full of css files called things like design_default.css and design_.css

I don't want to make changes to those files, because they're clearly auto generated, but I can't figure out where or how.

Any idea where they might be generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Files that you mention generated by modules. I believed you using custom theme too. You should not add your customise styles theme in those files. It's hard to maintain and debug. Instead add custom styles (if you need) to less files in your theme.

All those files is config theme from backend when you save config in admin. Modules write down it to file